# How do i put some space for the two output i obtained?

Tags: java

I wanted to make the **output** like this `Your ID (ID)(email)`

and this is what I've tried.

```
public class Testing1 {
        System.out.println("Enter your name:"); //Input command
        name = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your ID");
        ID = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your email");
        email = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Welcome\t"+name);   //Output command
        System.out.println("Your ID is:"+ID +email);
    } 
}
```

Comment: you should simply put an additional space in the string `System.out.println("Your ID is: " + ID + " " + email);`

Comment: @user10108425 did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To add a space between ID and email, just concatenate " " between the two variables:

```
System.out.println("Your ID is " + ID + " " + email);
```

If you want it in this format: Your ID (ID)(email), add brackets "(" and ")" around the two variables:

```
System.out.println("Your ID (" + ID + ")(" + email + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `concatenate` another empty `String` literal as follows:

```
System.out.println("Your ID is:"+ID+" "+email);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this output `Your ID (ID)(email)`

Yours:

```
System.out.println("Your ID is:"+ID +email);
```

Change it to:

```
System.out.println("Your ID " + "(" + ID + ") (" + email + ")");
```

Comment: @user10108425 did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The process of adding a space between two outputs can be obtained by using Java concatenation. In your case:

```
System.out.println("Your ID: ("+ID+") ("+email+")");
```

For more details about Java concatenation, you could check it out in this link. 
https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/combine-two-strings

I hope this helps you with your problem. Enjoy coding!